# How do i put a button on the same line as text? HTML

Tags: html, css

This is the code. I just started HTML yesterday so I am a beginner.

```css
Body {  
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  background-color: white; 
}  
button {   
       background-color: white;   
       width: 100%;  
        color: black;   
        padding: 15px;   
        margin: 10px 0px;   
        border: 3px solid #810020;   
        cursor: pointer;
         }   
 form {   
        border: 3px solid #1c1c1c;   
    }   
 input[type=text], input[type=password] {   
        width: 100%;   
        margin: 8px 0;  
        padding: 12px 20px;   
        display: inline-block;   
        border: 2px solid black;   
        box-sizing: border-box;   
    }  
 button:hover {   
        opacity: 0.7;   
    }   
  .btn {   
        width: auto;   
        padding: 10px 18px;  
        margin: 10px 5px;       
    }   
        
     
 .container {   
        padding: 25px;   
        background-color: #CA302D;  
    }
```

```html
<center>
    <h1><b>Home</b></h1>
</center>
<button type="button" class="btn"><a href="signup.html"> <b>Sign Up</b> </a></button>
<button type="button" class="btn"><a href="login.html"> <b>Log In</b> </a></button>
```

I've tried using inline-block and all but I think I was using it wrong.
I am trying to create a webpage but google sites didn't let me add a login page so I had to use HTML.

Comment: Do you mean to put the buttons on the same line as "Home", or on the same line as some other text that is not present at the moment? Because right now "Home" is the only text.

Comment: @Noahbruchell i dont really understand what you want cuz the text is already inside the button and you want text to be the same line as button? do you mean you want to put the text outside the button and make it the same line?

Comment: I meant put the buttons on same line as "Home" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wrap your elements with a `div` and use `flex` to get them in the same line

```css
Body {  
  font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
  background-color: white; 
}  
button {   
       background-color: white;   
       width: 100%;  
        color: black;   
        padding: 15px;   
        margin: 10px 0px;   
        border: 3px solid #810020;   
        cursor: pointer;
         }   
 form {   
        border: 3px solid #1c1c1c;   
    }   
 input[type=text], input[type=password] {   
        width: 100%;   
        margin: 8px 0;  
        padding: 12px 20px;   
        display: inline-block;   
        border: 2px solid black;   
        box-sizing: border-box;   
    }  
 button:hover {   
        opacity: 0.7;   
    }   
  .btn {   
        width: auto;   
        padding: 10px 18px;  
        margin: 10px 5px;       
    }   
        
     
 .container {   
        padding: 25px;   
        background-color: #CA302D;  
    }   
    
    .flex{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="flex">

<center>
    <h1><b>Home</b></h1>
</center>
<button type="button" class="btn"><a href="signup.html"> <b>Sign Up</b> </a></button>
<button type="button" class="btn"><a href="login.html"> <b>Log In</b> </a></button> 

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, although I was wondering if I could have the buttons justified/aligned right and the "Home" in the center.

Comment: you can do this,  add an empty div before the "Home" and updated this line `justify-content:between;`

Comment: you can use another way to do this, check this https://jsfiddle.net/r8hkvzca/